# Como obter o DateTime da internet?

Tags: c, datetime, internet, android-ndk

Como posso fazer para obter a data atual da internet, e converter o resultado para `char *data_atual`?

Exemplo dos sites pretendidos: `nist.time.gov` e/ou `time.windows.com`.

Gostaria de dois exemplos, um retornando apenas a data, e outro com a data e hora.

Existe alguma forma de fazer isso apenas com C?
Lembrando que usamos o horário de brasília `GMT -3`.

Comment: Florida, o que você já fez? Qual a dificuldade?

Comment: Vc esta se referindo a um objeto de tipo DateTime?

Comment: Não fiz nada, a dificuldade é completa, não sei como fazer isso em C, sem fazer uma gambiarra enorme. Creio que sim @DenerCarvalho, o que pretendo obter é a data/time, remotamente exibindo por exemplo `16/08/2016` e `16/08/2016 19:25` Não sei se fui bem claro.

Comment: @Florida acho que é seu dia de sorte =D tem vários [Client NTPs](https://github.com/search?l=C&q=client+ntp&type=Repositories&utf8=%E2%9C%93), pode escolher um deles e começar.

Comment: Vou ver se consigo fazer com socket, pode demorar, mas dependendo dos problemas que eu enfrentar, posso reformular a pergunta, caso não haja uma resposta. @AnthonyAccioly

Comment: Oi Florida, sim você sempre pode editar a pergunta incluindo um MVP. Se precisar de inspiração para resolver o problema com NTP de uma olhada [nessa pergunta do SOen](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1193955/how-to-query-an-ntp-server-using-c).